# User input choice with either head or tail command

Tags: bash, shell, tail, head

I want to prompt a user via command line & ask what specific rows need to be cut from a data file using either head or tail. My script will employ head and tail using the inputs as variables for both head and tail commands. This is what I have thus far along with the error message:

```
echo -n "What rows need to be cut from your data file: "
read before
read after
head -n $before /home/rent_list
tail -n $after /home/rent_list
```

Error message:

```
-bash: ./rent_list: bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

**Update:** This is what I am getting now:

```
 What rows need to be cut from your data file: 4

Mack Tools  Milwaukee Wisconsin mj414@yahoo.com 414 2248893
Terry Tools Orlando Florida 407@yahoo.com 407 2439812
Park Tools  Riviera Beach Florida tp123@hotmail.com 516 5370923
Bike Tools  Orlando Florida baptiste41@gmail.com 407 3420983
tail: /home/renter_list: invalid number of lines
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error-message seems to be saying that your script starts with `#!bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/bash` (that is, that you're missing a `/` before `bin/bash`).

---

**Update:** Your new error-message is because you're not entering a number. You have an `echo`, followed by two `read`s. For the first `read`, you're entering `4`, but for the second, you're just hitting Enter. So the `tail` command is `tail -n  /home/rent_list`.

If you want to use the same number for both commands, you can write:

```
echo -n "What rows need to be cut from your data file: "
read num_rows
head -n $num_rows /home/rent_list
tail -n $num_rows /home/rent_list
```

Comment: Thanks ruakh, that's what I needed to know.